# date compare in where clause of pandasql sqldf

Tags: python, pandas, pandasql

I am using pandasql sqldf to query over a dataframe , but unable to compare the date in where clause , getting invalid syntax error.

```
from pandasql import sqldf
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['2015-05-07','2021-05-07'], ['2020-03-06','2018-06-08']],columns= ['date1','date2'])

start = '2020-01-01'
dt= '2015-05-07'
testdf = sqldf('select * from df where strftime('%Y-%m-%d', start) > strftime('%Y-%m-%d',dt))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are facing formatting issues

```
testdf = sqldf('select * from df where strftime("%Y-%m-%d", {}) > strftime("%Y-%m-%d",{})'.format(start,dt))
```

Output:

```
       date1       date2
0  2015-05-07  2021-05-07
1  2020-03-06  2018-06-08
```

Comment: Thanks ,  is this a right way to compare dates in pandasql, or is this just happening a string comparison?